# Display posts links from a category group by year

Tags: categories, archives

I want to display posts links from a category group by year. Group by year becouse by default wordpress repeat the date for each post. I try use a code but I got all post in current year. How can I do it?
Example I want to do:

2010

- post link 20
- post link 19
- post    link 18
- ...
- post link 8

2009

- post link 7
- post link 6
- ...

The code:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('nopaging' => 1, /* desabilitar a paginacao pata obter todos os pots. O padrao e ordenado pela data */));
$prev_year = null;

query_posts('cat=27');

if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      $this_year = get_the_date('Y');
      if ($prev_year != $this_year) {
          // Year boundary
          if (!is_null($prev_year)) {
             // A list is already open, close it first
             echo '</ul>';
          }
          echo '<h2 class="titulo-conteudo">'. $this_year . '</h2>';
   echo '<div class="barra-amarela-4"></div>';
              echo '<ul>';
          }
      echo '<li>';

      // Imprimi o link do post.
  the_post(); ?>

                <div class="entry">
  <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(the_title()) ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


  </div>  

<?php 

      echo '</li>';
      $prev_year = $this_year;

   }
   echo '</ul>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [that original code on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397725/wordpress-how-can-i-display-post-link-group-by-year/3477409#3477409), but I didn't see your further replies because you posted them as answers and not as comments to my answer. I have tested the code now with a specific category and it works for me, but it needs one crucial change: the call to `the_post()` (which I completely forgot) must come right at the beginning of the `while ( have_posts() )` loop, otherwise the year will always lag one post behind. I have corrected that in the original answer.

If you want to specify multiple criteria for your query, you must combine them in the same function call. So not `query_posts('cat=27'); query_posts('nopaging=1');`, but `query_posts('cat=27&nopaging=1')`. You can also use the array format (as in my original example), I prefer that for readability.

A last change: if this is not the main loop of your page (and I suspect this code will end up in a sidebar, so not the main loop), [it is better not to use `query_posts()][2]`. Instead, try `get_posts()` and use the result of that. I did not know this when I wrote the original answer, but hanging around on this site learns you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a posts query that gives both the category and year values (as well as your nopaging, which is best done with posts_per_page=-1)

See the [codex article for query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for full details about prarameters you can pass into new WP_Query().

Here's the code for your question:

```
/**
 * Run a query for a specific category (cat=$cat_id) and year (&y=2008)
 * Also turn off the paging by setting posts_per_page to -1
 */
$year_and_category_query = new WP_Query("cat=$cat_id&year=2007&posts_per_page=-1");

/**
 * Run the loop on your new query
 */
while ($year_and_category_query->have_posts()) : $year_and_category_query->the_post();
    // Use the post with functions like the_title, or use the now global $post
endwhile;
```

Comment: When someone's in-line comments are in a non-English language and they're posting for support on an English-speaking forum, you should give them the benefit of the doubt and not start with a "read the question aloud" statement.  That's just rude.

Comment: *Jeremy Clarke* - I have to agree with *@EAMann*; let's give non-English speakers some slack. This ain't *wp-hackers*, after all. :-)

Comment: 9 years later I'm horrified at what I wrote. Must have been a really bad day. Updating it now so your comments won't make sense but the original version had me complaining about the grammar in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks to work well.. Since I was on here looking for solutions to another question I posted and came across this one, I thought I'd add how I accomplished this in one of my sites:

```
            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category_name=podcasts');
            $dates_array            = Array();
            $year_array             = Array();
            $i                      = 0;
            $prev_post_ts           = null;
            $prev_post_year         = null;
            $distance_multiplier    =  9;
        ?>

        <div class="post">

            <!--h2 class="title">< ? php the_title(); ?></h2-->

            <div id="archives" class="entry">   
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                $post_ts    =  strtotime($post->post_date);
                $post_year  =  get_the_date('Y');


                /* Handle the first year as a special case */
                if ( is_null( $prev_post_year ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <h3 class="archive_year"><?=$post_year?></h3>
                    <ul class="archives_list">
                    <?php
                }
                else if ( $prev_post_year != $post_year ) {
                    /* Close off the OL */
                    ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php

                    $working_year  =  $prev_post_year;

                    /* Print year headings until we reach the post year */
                    while ( $working_year > $post_year ) {
                        $working_year--;
                        ?>
                        <h3 class="archive_year"><?=$working_year?></h3>
                        <?php
                    }

                    /* Open a new ordered list */
                    ?>
                    <ul class="archives_list">
                    <?php
                }

                /* Compute difference in days */
                if ( ! is_null( $prev_post_ts ) && $prev_post_year == $post_year ) {
                    $dates_diff  =  ( date( 'z', $prev_post_ts ) - date( 'z', $post_ts ) ) * $distance_multiplier;
                }
                else {
                    $dates_diff  =  0;
                }
            ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j'); ?><sup><?php the_time('S') ?></sup></span> 
                    <span class="linked"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span> 
                    <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link(__('0 comments', 'warp'), __('1 comment', 'warp'), __('% comments', 'warp')); ?></span> 
                </li>
            <?php
                /* For subsequent iterations */
                $prev_post_ts    =  $post_ts;
                $prev_post_year  =  $post_year;
            endwhile;

            /* If we've processed at least *one* post, close the ordered list */
            if ( ! is_null( $prev_post_ts ) ) {
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>

            </div><!--entry-->

            </div><!--post-->
```

This eliminates multiple query_posts calls and is really easy to control styling, etc.. hope this helps someone who may be wanted to see various solutions to this :)

Great work again, on your orig. solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code got very broken when posted. From what I can see multiple `query_posts()` are bad idea in most cases. Please correct your code if you want better assessment.

Personally I would use plugin for this, there are plenty of excellent archive plugins around. I currently play with [Smart Archives Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/). It allows easily to get posts by month/year in specific category:

`smart_archives( array(
    'format' => 'list',
    'include_cat' => 27
    ));`